# Find a lattice basis given too many points

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, lattices

Fix a discrete addition subgroup in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Given a finite spanning set, how can one find a group basis?

Comment: I think there is some translation to this question, although they also cared about basis size https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124744/integral-basis-of-orthogonal-complement?rq=1

Comment: I think a solution to this problem is given in
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-16078-7_69.
But I do not have online access to that paper.

Comment: Do you intend the $b$’s to be among the $v$’s, or it doesn’t matter?

Comment: @LSpice Doesn't matter. I think in some cases it might not even be possible.

Comment: There will always exist a basis, so it is not clear what is meant by "it might not even be possible". If this is a reference to the problem where the $b$'s must be among the $v$'s, then sure, it can be impossible. There are examples of lattices which have the property that the minimal vectors generate the lattice, but no basis of minimal vectors exist for $L$.

Comment: @JosiahPark I agree. $${}$$ Also, if one can find an invertible linear map $A$ which takes $L$ into $AL\subset \mathbb{Z}^d$, then one can compute the Smith normal form of $B=A[v_1,\dots, v_k]\in \mathbb{Z}^{d\times k}$, yielding invertible integer matrices $S,T$ with $SBT=D$ diagonal. Then the nonzero columns of $S^{-1}D=BT$ form a basis for $AL$. So the desired basis can be computed as $A^{-1}BT$, with indices given by $T$.

Comment: Yes, this works in the case when the lattice is an integer lattice. Section 14 of Lenstra's tutorial here: https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~psh/ANTproc/06hwl.pdf also gives an algorithm for this case. In the general case, an algorithm is given (Edit) in: J. Hastad, B. Just, J.C. Lagarias and C.P. Schnorr, Polynomial time algorithms for finding integer relations among real numbers, Proceedings STACS 86. This is the paper mentioned above by @MartinSeysen.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm.

Comment: The "Lovasz Integer Relation Algorithm" directly solves the restricted version. $${}$$ I don't see how the general case is solved. The "Simultaneous Relations Algorithm" seems most applicable: given a $n\times \ell$ real matrix $\mathbf{V}$ it produces a basis $\mathbf{B}$ of $r$ integer $\ell$-vectors where $\mathbf{V}\mathbf{B}=0$. It gives me a basis for the kernel lattice, not a basis for the image lattice
.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a $d$-dimensional discrete addition subgroup $L\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Call the spanning elements $v_1,\dots, v_k\in L$ and the matrix whose columns are these $v$'s as $V\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$. We seek a group basis $b_1,\dots,b_d\in L$.

Two solutions. I have tried the first one since it is readily implementable.

---

The LLL algorithm is strong enough to perform this reduction.

Affix $I_{k\times k}$ to the top of $V\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ forming $V^\ast \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+k)\times k}$. Run the [LLL algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) on the columns of $V^\ast$ using the seminorm that equals the norm of the bottom $n$ components. The nonzero last-$n$-components of the LLL-reduced vectors will form a basis for the desired subgroup. The first $k$ components give coordinates for this basis in terms of input vectors $V$.

(Or also, form $V^\ast$ by instead affixing $\varepsilon \cdot I_{k\times k}$. For $\varepsilon$ small enough, the LLL algorithm with the usual norm does the same thing.)

Johannes Buchmann and Michael Pohst. Computing a lattice basis from a
system of generating vectors. In *European Conference on Computer Algebra*,
pages 54–63. Springer, 1987.

---

Run an exhaustive *Simultaneous Integer Relations Algorithm* on $V\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$, the matrix whose columns are $v_1,\dots, v_k$. This algorihtm finds a matrix $R\in \mathbb{Z}^{k\times r}$ of all, say, $r$ independent integer relations for the input vectors, i.e. $VR=0\in \mathbb{R}^n.$ Now run the *S. I. R. A.* on $R'$ to find a matrix $S\in \mathbb{Z}^{k\times r^\ast}$. Columns of $VS$ form the desired basis.